# C decimal to binary converter (16 bits)

Tags: c, binary, decimal

I'm trying to convert a decimal number into binary (16 bits max). My function works perfectly for up to 8 bits but when I want to print numbers up to 16 bits, it stop printing characters.
I used "int" as my data type for 8 bits but since I want to store 16 bits I'm using an unsigned long int in every variable.

Here's the code:

```
/* Program to convert decimal to binary (16 bits) */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *byte_to_binary_str(long unsigned int byte);

int main()
{

 printf("%s",byte_to_binary_str(32768));  //1000000 0000000
    return 0;
}

char *byte_to_binary_str(long unsigned int byte)
{
    static char bit_string[17];
    bit_string[0] = '\0';

    long unsigned int mask;
    for (mask = 2^15; mask > 0; mask >>= 1) {
        /* Check if the mask bit is set */
        strcat(bit_string, byte & mask ? "1" : "0");
    }

    return bit_string;
}
```

My output gives me:

```
0000
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.063 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Anyone know why is this happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: C `unsigned int` is guaranteed to be at least 16 bits wide.  You could also consider one of the explicit-width types, such as `uint16_t`.

Comment: `2^15` doesn't mean what you think it does. [See this chart](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic) for what it *actually* does.

Comment: That was my problem. I ALWAYS forget about that.. I'm using pow(2,15) and it's working now, thanks a lot

Comment: `pow(2,15)` : the new, more expensive way of writing `32768`

Comment: you are smart enough to understand right shift yet not enough to understand left shift?

Comment: `pow` probably is optimised for that case. But arguably better anyway just to have an explicit constant `0x8000` or `(0x1<<15)`.

Comment: Also, DO NOT USE `strcat()` unless you know what you're doing. You, DON'T. Read about [tag:c] strings.

Comment: Well I could had written 32768 but I wanted to save this code and put something in there that I could understand. could write comments in it but it's fine like this too.

Comment: Thanks for the tips everyone. And user3528438 I do but I'm a begginer in this, the thought of using a left shift as a constant didn't come naturally to me.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Or the more appropriate `uint_least16_t`.

Comment: @kaylum `0x1<<15` and `1<<15` result in the same type `int` even on 16-bit systems and `1<<15` is easier to read.  Suggest `1u<<15` to prevent shifting into the sign bit.

Comment: Why not `bit_string[17] = ""; char *p = bit_string + 16; for (; byte; byte >>= 1) *--p = (byte & 1) ? '1' : '0'; return p;` ?

Answer (score 4):

```
mask = 2^15;
```

does not set the value of `mask` to what you are expecting `2^15` is no 2 raised to the power 15. It is bitwise XOR of `2` and `15`.

You need something that is `1000 0000 0000 0000` in binary. That number will be `0x8000` in hex. Hence, use:

```
mask = 0x8000;
```

You can also use something that makes sense in your algorithm.

```
mask = 1u << 15;
```

Comment: As OP's system might have 16-bit `int/unsigned`, better to use `1u << 15`.